# Is Google Maps API key v2 eligible for MapView element?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, api-key

I have created application using MapView element and custom itemized overlay. Then, accidentally, I have lost my API key v1. Unfortunately, it is not possible to obtain a new v1 key anymore and I don't want to re-write application using MapFragment at all. MapFragment does not support most of MapView's API, that is the problem.

I have tried inserting generated v2 key into the MapView element but it does not work. I am not sure if it is a problem of key versions or I have done something wrong.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. have you rectified yours?

Comment: It was allowed to generate v1 keys in that time. Now I guess you have to generate V2 key and transfer your code to V2 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, accidentally, I have lost my API key v1

Then please stop all software development until you learn how to maintain proper backups of your development machine.

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to obtain a new v1 key anymore

Yes, it is. Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey):

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 3rd, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version.

At the time of this writing, it is before March 3rd, 2013. Hence, you can visit [the Maps API key signup page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup) and request a key.

> MapFragment does not support most of MapView's API, that is the problem

I have not yet run into anything that V2 cannot do that V1 could. Yes, you will have to port your code over to use the new classes and methods. There is a decent chance that you will wind up with less code overall, though.

> I have tried inserting generated v2 key into the MapView element but it does not work.

If you are referring to the original `MapView` from the Maps SDK add-on, the two services use different key systems AFAIK.

Comment: Just to clarify, can I target Android 2.3 using the new Google API V2?  The tutorial assumes 4.2 and I'm pretty sure fragments were introduced after 2.3.

Comment: @Michael: "can I target Android 2.3 using the new Google API V2?" -- yes. "The tutorial assumes 4.2 and I'm pretty sure fragments were introduced after 2.3." -- Maps V2 comes with `MapFragment` for native API Level 11 fragments, `SupportMapFragment` for use with the Android Support Library's backport of fragments, and `MapView` for use in places where you are electing not to use fragments for whatever reason.